# In Access VBA, what's the difference between GroupLevel and Section objects..?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA, what are the major differences & issues between GroupLevel objects and Section objects..? I thought I understood, but then I got to a point in my code where I realized I didn't. I'm writing some code that automates the formatting of controls on a report that's open in design view. And while it's not normally necessary to know of Sections for this, the code does operate based on which section a control is in.

From looking at the help file, online, and the Locals window of the IDE in debug mode, it seems to me GroupLevel is the greater of the two...almost. A GroupLevel object represents a report group level, if there's any grouping. But then a Section object for a header, footer, both, or neither will stem from a GroupLevel object, based on its properties.

It's tempting to say that you can't have a Section without a GroupLevel, but there will always be a Detail section, even with no grouping. And moving up from there will be report header/footer, and page header/footer, and whether or not these exist determines whether or not a Section object exists for them. So I suppose it would be more accurate to say you can't have more than five Section objects without a GroupLevel for each of them.

And this is just what I've found for Reports. I haven't even dusted the snow off the tip of the iceberg for forms yet. Any insights & explanations in that vein would be most appreciated.

There's a closely related issue: since GroupLevel objects and Section objects don't have their own respective collections (such as "GroupLevels" or "Sections"), are there any .Count properties for them hidden elsewhere..? Or does a programmer simply have to follow the conceptual logic and iterate through .GroupLevel(n) or .Section(n) until a runtime error occurs to indicate "n" doesn't exist..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sections* are the "physical" parts of the report/form: headers, footers, detail.

*GroupLevels* are logical, determined by your data and how you define Groups in the report.

Comment: Ahhh...that's a good way of putting it. So with further reading and experimentation last night, I came to the realization that all of the Index numbers for GroupLevels and Sections are reserved and limited. There can only be 10 groups, each with two sections, a header and footer. Any form or report has a detail, document and footer, and page hander and footer, with the groups after that, in that order (leading from the Access.acSection enumeration). That's a total of 25 maximum possible sections. Does that seem correct..?

Comment: That makes sense, though I've never done the counting myself.